# Suppose that a sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, recurrence-relations

Suppose that a sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$ of numbers satisfies $a_{n+1}=a_n/(a_n+1)$ for
all $n\ge1$. Show that
$$a_n=\frac{a_1}{(n-1)a_1+1}$$
Would I have to use induction to solve this? If so, how? The first statement of the question is confusing me.

Comment: This doesn't make sense; $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n}$ by the first condition!

Comment: Presumably you mean $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{a_n+1}$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Right, and the hint is that's the same as $\,\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{a_n}+1\,$.

Comment: That's right, sorry I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dxiv's hint:
$$\frac1{a_{n+1}}=\frac1{a_n}+1$$
$$\frac1{a_n}=\frac1{a_1}+n-1$$
$$a_n=\frac1{1/a_1+n-1}=\frac{a_1}{(n-1)a_1+1}$$

Comment: Okay that makes more sense. So a good way to show this would be to first write out a sequence that satisfies the first condition then show how your work proves that last equation?

Comment: @JenniferHall It's all manipulation of the given recurrence...

Comment: Oh, so I don't even have to show that?

Comment: @JenniferHall Yah...