# Olympic question about functions

Tags: functions, contest-math, problem-solving

I have been trying to solve the following question:

Let $f: \left \{ 1,2,... \right \}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(n) - f(n+1) = f(n)f(n+1)$. If $f(2020) = \frac{1}{4040}$, find $f(1)$

The answer is f(1) = $\frac{1}{2021}$.

Using a simple algebraic manipulation, I found that if $f(2020) = \frac{1}{4040}$ then $f(2019) = \frac{1}{4039}$, what is interesting for the problem considering the answer...

How can i progress? Or there a trick way in these question

Comment: I mean, can't you repeat that algebraic manipulation?

Comment: Well, we have $f(n)=\frac {f(n+1)}{1-f(n+1)}$ so you can always proceed backwards.  If you try this, a simple pattern emerges and it should be a simple matter to prove that it holds.

Comment: Divide both sides by $f(n) f(n+1)$ to get $\frac{1}{f(n+1)} - \frac{1}{f(n)} = 1$. We're given $\frac{1}{f(2020)} = 4040$ so this pretty easily gives $\frac{1}{f(1)} = 2021$.

Comment: @Ant Brilliant! Please edit it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks you! @Ant

Comment: @Ant Technically you can't divide unless you know $f(n)f(n+1)$ is not zero. Of course that's probably handlable anyway.

Comment: @Ant No problem: before dividing, just notice (by decreasing induction) that all $f(n)$'s (from $f(2020)$ to $f(1)$) are $\ne0.$

Comment: If $f(n)f(n+1)=0$ then $f(n)=f(n+1)=0$ which is not the case

Comment: Related: [Closed form of the recurrence relation: $x_{n+1} = {x_n \over b + x_n}$, $x_1 = a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2938196) and [Suppose that a sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2549924)

Comment: One reason I'm pointing out these "case checks" is that they're probably the reason why this is considered an Olympic-level question: it seems easy at first glance, and, well, it is still easy, but you do need to pay attention. That's just my opinion though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equivalently we can show that $f(n+1) = \frac{f(n)}{f(n) + 1}$

By recursive application, easy to show $f(n+k) = \frac{f(n)}{k * f(n) + 1}$

Now let $n=1$ and $k=2019$, then

$$f(2020) = \frac{f(1)}{2019 * f(1) + 1} = \frac{1}{4040}$$
$$\Rightarrow 4040*f(1) = 2019 * f(1) + 1 \Rightarrow f(1) = \frac{1}{2021}$$

Comment: Same minor issue as what I commented to Ant, you need to handle the potential case $f(n) = -1$ separately. I'm saying minor issue because it's probably not big of a deal, but still.